# Is `validates_presence_of` deprecated (as of Rails 3)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

According the the [Rails 3 release notes, `validate_presence_of` is deprecated](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#patches-and-deprecations).

However, I can see no mention of this in [the documentation (for v4.0.2)](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of).

Was this an error in the release notes/did it get re-precated/is the documentation wrong?

Comment: Guess they change their mind.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax has changed to:

```
validates :some_field, :presence => true
```

Referrence: [Link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I just faced the same question when I migrated to Rails 3 , thought `validate_presence_of` is deprecated, but then came across this solution. So, I posted.

Answer (score 1):

It's a soft deprecation. Both syntaxes still exist, but the `validates` is newer and 'preferred'.

Comment: Can you explain why it is newer and 'preferred'?

Comment: well, it's newer because it was introduced after the other syntax. It's likely preferred because it allows you to group validations together into one call - instead of `validates_presence_of :foo, validates_inclusion_of :foo, validates_length_of :foo`, etc. you can just do `validates :foo, presence: true, inclusion: {in: [whatever]}, length: {maximum: 3}`...

Answer (score -1):

The method is still there, but since Rails 3 it is defined in a slightly different namespace than before.

Before Rails 3:

```
 ActiveModel::Validations::ClassMethods#validates_presence_of
```

Since Rails 3:

```
ActiveRecord::Validations::ClassMethods#validates_presence_of
ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods#validates_presence_of
```

I had to look very close to see the differences.

Conclusion: just keep using `validates_presence_of`!